# Найти уникальное значение в массиве. C

Tags: c, массивы

В программе формирую массив, который выгдяит примерно так: types [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1].
Мне нужно найти и вывести уникальные значения, для данного примера: 1,2,3,4,5. То есть вернее будет выразиться - вывести все встречающиеся значения. Как это можно реализовать в С?

Comment: Диапазон значений какой?..

Comment: Если массив можно изменять - сортируйте и идите по нему, выводя только новые (не равные предыдущему) значения.

Comment: @Harry диапазон 0-0xFF. И да, массив можно изменять.

Comment: Тогда см. мой дополненный ответ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не особо заморачиваться и решать в лоб, то вот простейший алгоритм с квадратичной сложностью. Суть - бежим по основному массиву, и каждого кандидата проверяем, нет ли его ещё в списке, если нет - добавляем. Я не заморачивался с перевыделением памяти - просто завел максимально возможный массив.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    #define size 10
    int a[size] = {1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1};
    int b[size] = {0};
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < found; j++) {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) { c = 1; break;}
        }
        if (c == 0) { b[found] = a[i]; found++;}
    }
    printf("found = %d\n", found);
    for (int i = 0; i < found; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Если массив можно сортировать, тогда это можно сделать за n*log n

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// с этим компаратором нужно быть аккуратным:)
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
    #define size 10
    int a[size] = {1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1};
    qsort(a, size, sizeof(a[0]), compare);

    int c = a[0];
    printf("%3d", c);
    for (int i = 1; i<size; i++) {
        if (a[i] != c) {
            c = a[i];
            printf("%3d", c);
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```

в этом случае даже нет второго массива - можно сразу выводить.

Если же известен диапазон значений, то можно и линейно сделать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
int main()
{
    #define size 10
    int a[size] = {1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,1,1};
    // 1000 - это максимальное значение, которое может быть в исходном массива (да, на самом деле 999, но мы все знаем +-1)
    #define BUF_SIZE 1000
    int buf[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE*sizeof(a[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buf[a[i]] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++) {
        if (buf[i] > 0) {
            printf("%3d", i);
        }
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: не совсем понял как работает последний вариант кода. Диапазон значений известен 0-0xFF. Что значит buf[ a[i] ] = 1? Это как?

Comment: В последнем варианте изначально в массиве нули. Для найденных элементов ставим единицу. Повторная 1 не меняет картину. Вам размер буфера равный 256 будет норм.

Comment: То есть мы создаем массив buf, выделяем на него память и забиваем нулями его.
Потом все элементы меняем на 1-цу. После чего выводим просто счетчик?

Comment: Нет. Мы меняем те элементы, индексы которых равны исходным элементам. Счётчиков у меня нет

Answer (score 2):

Ну, тогда покажу и я свое решение, раз дали квадратичное :)

```
int cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_)
{
    int a = *(int*)a_;
    int b = *(int*)b_;
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,1,2,18,43,14,3,4,5,5,5,1,1};

    qsort(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]),sizeof(int),cmp);

    printf("%d ",a[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
        if (a[i] != a[i-1]) printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
```

Для такого маленького диапазона `0-0xFF` проще будет

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,1,2,18,43,14,3,4,5,5,5,1,1};
    int b[256] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
        if (b[a[i]] == 0) b[a[i]]++;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        if (b[i]) printf("%d ",i);
}
```